# Is it normal to have so many (such long) Layer Root #document paints?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console, parallax, timeline

[image: console timeline screenshot]

I'm attempting to improve the performance of some scroll effects (fade when enter view, parallax). I'm a bit confused as to what is causing the issue when the Layer root is #document.

Is there a way to track this down?

Thanks.

Comment: There are several factors to what goes into paint and how many are called for etc.  A few ideas - 1) Limit the amount of calls with a short timeout 2) Hardware accelerate with CSS like transform translate3d  3) Use requestanimationframe to level your framerate so you don't have spikes that make things choppy. 4) Remove any unnecessary calls to change CSS like width, top etc cause they will trigger a paint.

Comment: Thanks @Dylan. I've tried 1,2,and 4 but as I dug deeper I noticed that #document is almost always the element getting painted and that didn't seem right to me. Shouldn't it be specific elements on the document? Does this just mean that element getting painted doesn't have a parent other than the #document?

Comment: It's hard to tell without it in front of me, but if you go through the call stack of each I believe you can find the function that is causing the paint. From there I would imagine you would find something that is being manipulated or resized in some way as to cause the paint. The normal, like jQuery scrollTop should not cause it to paint.

Comment: I just remembered, this looks like its a CSS issue, try checking off the checkboxes of any heavy CSS in dev tools, like shadows, corners, gradients, and rerunning your timeline.